# android how to properly set default language for an app, even after turning off the device

Tags: android, localization, locale, android-preferences

I'm quite new to android dev, and I have a little problem of localization.
I have an app in which the user may choose to use an other default language than the current  language of the device.
For example, a French user who live in Germany and who have his phone set to "German", could want to use my app in french (for various reasons), but not to set the default language of his phone in French.

My app have only ONE activity, into which I load and unload some views.
It's a very simple app, but with large contents (texts and images).

To accomplish this, I use the code below.

It works well, but there are some issues :

- When the user chose a new language with the appropriate button, and relaunch the app (or if I force the app to finish()...) : ONLY THE FIRST VIEW uses the new language. The next views are still set to the previous language.
- If the user chose to turn off his device, same issue : only the first view of the activity is set to the choosen language (the variable is read from the preferences.).
- However, if the user chose to relaunch the app a second time, all views and subviews are correctly set to the new language.
- And, also, if the user has previously relaunched the app at least one time, each language change is successfully accomplished. No need to relaunch the app a second time.

So, is there a way to correctly set the new language

- immediately after the first relaunch of the app
- if the user have previously turned of and on his device

Any help will be appreciated. 
Here is the code I use (simplified):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences myPrefs;
    myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("langage", MODE_PRIVATE);  
    String langageToLoad = myPrefs.getString("langageToLoad", "");
    changeLangage(langageToLoad);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     (...some other code...)
    }

public void setLangageEn(View view){
    changeLangage( "en");
    setPreference( "en"); 
    // finish(); // optionnal
    }

public void changeLangage(String langage) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(langage); 
    Locale systemLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    if (systemLocale != null && systemLocale.equals(locale)) {
    return;
    }
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

public void setPreference( String langage){
    SharedPreferences languagepref = getSharedPreferences("langage",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = languagepref.edit();
    editor.putString("langageToLoad",langage );
    editor.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following thing: **just because you finish() one activity, the previous activities don't need to be closed and therefor MIGHT call onResume() and just "jump over" onCreate()**, they aren't out of the memory yet and don't call onCreate() (which comes before onResume()), where you implement your language check.

---

One thing to avoid this issue, might be to create a custom "Application class" (extends Application) and there, check the localize-preference and set it to a field with getter and setter methods. To get the application instance then (which is created on the application start!(not when just starting a second activity..) you can do ((CustomApp)Context.getApplicationContext).getCustomLocalization() in your activities..

However. To really load up the new language settings in every activity, be sure to check it in onResume() and set the language 1. to the field in CustomApp and 2. to the preference (maybe with the same setter method?) when changing it. Then finish() your settings activity and recreate it to load the new settings.